# Update Exisiting data in Firebase database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I need to update my existing data in the firebase.When compling code there is no error but application unfortunately stop when i press the Update button.In my Database there are two child nodes snakes and Habitat.for that nodes same key is used to store data.Log cat shows that Null pointer exception at  `String name=SciName.getSelectedItem().toString();` when override the onclick method.

```
 public void showUpdatedDialog(final String snakeID, String snakeName)  // dialog box
{
    AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder=new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    LayoutInflater  inflater=getLayoutInflater();
    final View dialogView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.update_dialog,null);
    dialogBuilder.setView(dialogView);

    final Button updatebutton=(Button)dialogView.findViewById(R.id.btn_upload_snake);
    final Spinner SciName=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.scientificName);
    final EditText Snakename=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.etSnakeName);
    final EditText Habitat1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.etHabitat1);
    final EditText Habitat2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.etHabitat2);
    final EditText Tretment=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.etTreatment);
    final EditText  Behaviour=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.etBehaviour);
    final EditText Venomousness=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.etVenomousness);
    final EditText Distribution=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.etDistribution);
    final EditText Habit=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.etHabit);
    final EditText Reproduction=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.etReproduction);


    dialogBuilder.setTitle("Updating Snake details::"+snakeName);

    final AlertDialog alertDialog=dialogBuilder.show();
    alertDialog.show();




    updatebutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String name=SciName.getSelectedItem().toString();
            String Sname=Snakename.getText().toString().trim();
            String H1=Habitat1.getText().toString().trim();
            String H2=Habitat2.getText().toString().trim();
            String Treatment=Tretment.getText().toString().trim();
            String Habit1=Habit.getText().toString().trim();
            String Behaviour2=Behaviour.getText().toString().trim();
            String Distribution2=Distribution.getText().toString().trim();
            String Reproduction2=Reproduction.getText().toString().trim();
            String Venom=Venomousness.getText().toString().trim();

            if(TextUtils.isEmpty(Sname)){
                Snakename.setError("Name Is Required");
                return;
            }
            updatesnake(snakeID,name,Sname,Treatment,Behaviour2,Venom,Distribution2,Habit1,Reproduction2,H1,H2);
            alertDialog.dismiss();
        }
    });


}


public  void updatesnake( String id, String SCINAME,String snakename, String TREATMENT,String BEHAVIOUR,String VENOMOUSNESS,String DISTRIBUTION,String HABIT,String REPRODUCTION,String HABITAT1,String HABITAT2){ // update details to snakes.
     DatabaseReference databaseSnake=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("snake").child("id");
     Snake snake=new Snake(id ,SCINAME,snakename,TREATMENT,BEHAVIOUR,VENOMOUSNESS,DISTRIBUTION,HABIT,REPRODUCTION);
     databaseSnake.setValue(snake);

     DatabaseReference databaseSnake2=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("habitat");
     Habitat habitat=new Habitat(HABITAT1,HABITAT2);
     databaseSnake2.child(id).setValue(habitat);

    Toast.makeText(this,"UPDATE IS SUCCESSFUL",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
```

}

Comment: Based on the log, the error seems to be that no item is selected in the spinner. Doesn't seem to have anything to do with Firebase unless you are having an issue loading the data into the spinner. Could you ensure that some item is selected in the spinner, and then press 'Update', and see if the behaviour persists?

Comment: yes i have selected item in spinner but same thing happens.@TheGamer007

Comment: Could you update the question with the exact log? The `getSelectedItem` method returns `null` only if no item is selected. So is it possible your spinner object itself was not initialized properly and is `null`?

Comment: Where is the log?